# How do I undo my vote to close?

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Maybe it's just me but on countless occasions I've wrongly voted to close after misreading the question (oops).  Either that, or the OP has modified their question following a comment to bring it in line with the types of questions allowed in the FAQ.

If you're on 4 close votes with no way to undo and someone comes along and decides ooh, 4 votes, I'll add my 5th one... without really thinking, you then have to go back through the whole reopen process again.  I doubt this happens very often to be honest but it would still be very useful if there was a way to undo your own vote to close.

**Is there a way to undo my own vote to close for a question?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, but you won't like the fact that you have to wait three days for it to automagically disappear. Your best bet is to leave a comment stating that you disagree with the/your decision.

If you happen to close the question, then you flag it for moderator attention. If they agree/disagree with your flag or comment, they will make sure appropriate action will be taken.

Problem solved!

Comment: I can live with that :-) thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes; just click the "close" button again and click "Retract Close Vote" any time before the question gets closed or the close vote expires. However, you should note that once you have retracted a close vote on a question, you can no longer vote to close the same question again.

I'm not completely sure as to whether or not retracting a close vote will add back to your close vote count, though...