# Undo Flag Submission

Tags: support, flagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Revoking flags and close votes](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2772/revoking-flags-and-close-votes)

I accidentally flagged a question with the wrong option. Is there any way to un-submit, undo, or change that flag so that a moderator doesn't have to bother with it?

Answer (score 6):

Nope, but you could either leave a comment on the question/answer so moderators know your flag  is no longer correct. Or you could try [notifying the moderators in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator), so we know we can dismiss it.

In the end, moderators are human error handlers, so we check your flag and if we deem it invalid, we won't act on it. So as long as you can avoid this from happening very often, there's little harm done. If you do, we would deem your flags invalid and at some point your flags would get very little priority.

But for now, no need to worry

Comment: It's for this reason I'm glad we don't have (public) flag weight anymore.

Comment: You can also flag it again and say "oops, sorry, ignore that flag, here's what I really meant". We'll generally just dismiss it and move on.

Comment: @nhinkle I just tried to flag a question twice and I got an error message that I had already flagged it, so I'm not entirely sure if that's true

Comment: Huh. I thought with custom mod messages you could do that, but maybe it's changed. YMMV, apparently.

Comment: @nhinkle Flagging twice never works. I've wanted to do that a couple of times but you get the error once you submit the form.

Comment: Yesterday, I went to flag something twice (not realizing I had already flagged it the first time), and it seemed that the second flag was just silently dropped/ignored.  In both cases, the flag reason was "not an answer", so that may have made a difference.