# What can I do with old questions that I think should be closed?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

Since I have started to use the review page, I have looked at many old questions. Some of them  I believe should be closed (like [What is the fastest BitTorrent client?](https://superuser.com/questions/35649/what-is-the-fastest-bittorrent-client/219598#219598) for example). While I can cast my vote, I find it highly unlikely that it will ever accumulate enough to get closed, and if it merits it, subsequently deleted.

Is there a way to look at posts that have close votes cast on them?

Comment: well, if you *really* want something closed, there's always the vote to close chatroom. Since close votes apparently expire after a time, only recent close votes count

Comment: Huh, why is that?

Comment: its just the way its designed. see http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2285/how-do-i-undo-my-vote-to-close

Comment: You'll often find a user or two who disagree with your question. Leaving their votes around indefinitely will a) motivate others to vote on "borderline" questions (think `software-rec` where it officially *entirely* depends on whether it's "interesting") and b) make it much easier to accumulate such votes over a very long time. If five users on the site thought your question wasn't good over a 6 month period, is this *really* reason enough to close it?

Comment: Makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Users with more than 10,000 reputation can view questions with votes to close on the `/review/close` page.

Currently I have put in a [request to have that change.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111838/why-was-review-close-taken-away-for-under-10k-users-can-it-be-put-back)

For those under 10k, after casting the vote, use the [Super User: Vote To Close Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117/super-user-vote-to-close-delete). Posting a link there will allow us to vote to close it, and moderators check it often.

Comment: Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another option if you find a large number of old posts you think should be deleted is to post the list on meta. Other users can then take a look at the list and comment on whether they should be removed, and a moderator can then go through and close/delete as appropriate once the community has had a chance to check out the proposed closures.

The vote-to-close room is going to be your best option though, and I would encourage you to use it!